# Netbeans token parsing error with json when adding stuff outside brackets

Tags: json, netbeans

I have external properties.json file.

```
properties = {
    name: 'alice',
    age: '19'
}
```

In browser, other js files can access properties.json and everything works fine. However, Netbeans recognizes this as a token parsing error, and doesn't let me deploy the project. Error dissapears if I delete "properties =". What exactly is going on and what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equals `=` is not a valid JSON token. Just have a look at the [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) and format your JSON accordingly.